# Terraform fails to create ingress (could not find the requested resource ingresses.extensions)

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, minikube

I'm using minikube locally.
The following is the `.tf` file I use to create my kubernetes cluster:

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  config_path = "~/.kube/config"
}

resource "kubernetes_namespace" "tfs" {
  metadata {
    name = "tfs" # terraform-sandbox
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_deployment" "golang_webapp" {
  metadata {
    name      = "golang-webapp"
    namespace = "tfs"
    labels = {
      app = "webapp"
    }
  }
  spec {
    replicas = 3
    selector {
      match_labels = {
        app = "webapp"
      }
    }
    template {
      metadata {
        labels = {
          app = "webapp"
        }
      }
      spec {
        container {
          image             = "golang-docker-example"
          name              = "golang-webapp"
          image_pull_policy = "Never" # this is set so that kuberenetes wont try to download the image but use the localy built one
          liveness_probe {
            http_get {
              path = "/"
              port = 8080
            }
            initial_delay_seconds = 15
            period_seconds        = 15
          }

          readiness_probe {
            http_get {
              path = "/"
              port = 8080
            }
            initial_delay_seconds = 3
            period_seconds        = 3
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


resource "kubernetes_service" "golang_webapp" {
  metadata {
    name      = "golang-webapp"
    namespace = "tfs"
    labels = {
      app = "webapp_ingress"
    }
  }
  spec {
    selector = {
      app = kubernetes_deployment.golang_webapp.metadata.0.labels.app
    }
    port {
      port        = 8080
      target_port = 8080
      protocol    = "TCP"
    }
    # type = "ClusterIP"
    type = "NodePort"
  }
}

resource "kubernetes_ingress" "main_ingress" {
  metadata {
    name      = "main-ingress"
    namespace = "tfs"
  }

  spec {
    rule {
      http {
        path {
          backend {
            service_name = "golang-webapp"
            service_port = 8080
          }
          path = "/golang-webapp"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When executing `terraform apply`, I am successfully able to create all of the resources except for the ingress.

The error is:

```
Error: Failed to create Ingress 'tfs/main-ingress' because: the server could not find the requested resource (post ingresses.extensions)

with kubernetes_ingress.main_ingress,
   on main.tf line 86, in resource "kubernetes_ingress" "main_ingress":
   86: resource "kubernetes_ingress" "main_ingress" {
```

When I try to create an ingress service with kubectl using the same configuration as the one above (only in `.yaml` and using the `kubectl apply` command) it works, so it seems that kubectl & minikube are able to create this type of ingress, but terraform cant for some reason...

Thanks in advance for any help!

Edit 1:

adding the `.yaml` that I'm able to create the ingress with

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  namespace: tfs
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: golang-webapp
                port:
                  number: 8080
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue can be related to the ingress classname. May be you need to explicitely provide it in your .tf:

```
metadata {
    name = "example"
    annotations = {
      "kubernetes.io/ingress.class" = "nginx or your classname"
    }
```

Or may be it's ingresses.extensions that does not exist in your cluster. Can you provide the .yaml that executed correctly ?

Comment: i've tried to use the annotations tag that way, did not work :(
I added the .yaml file to the question

Comment: I see in your yaml file that your ingress is created with apiVersion: **networking.k8s.io/v1** . However when you use terraform resource _kubernetes_ingress_, it used **extensions/v1beta1**.  What if you used this resource https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs/resources/ingress_v1 instead ?

Comment: It worked! my bad I did not see that there is also the v1 option

Answer (score 14):

The `kubernetes_ingress` resource generate an ingress with an `apiVersion` which is not supported by your kubernetes cluster. You have to use `[kubernetes_ingress_v1][1]` resource which looks similar to `kubernetes_ingress` resource with some diferences. For your example, it will be like this :

```
resource "kubernetes_ingress_v1" "jenkins-ingress" {
   metadata {
      name        = "example-ingress"
      namespace   = "tfs"
      annotations = {
        "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target" = "/$1"
      }
   }
   spec {
      rule {
        http {
         path {
           path = "/"
           backend {
             service {
               name = "golang-webapp"
               port {
                 number = 8080
               }
             }
           }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should help using `kubernetes_ingress_v1`

```
locals{
  ingress_rules = [
    {
      service_path = "/"
      service_name = "golang-webapp"
      service_port = 8080
    }
}

resource "kubernetes_ingress_v1" "jenkins-ingress" {

  metadata {
    annotations = var.ingress_annotations
    name        = "example-ingress"
    namespace   = "tfs"
    labels      = var.labels
  }
  spec {
    ingress_class_name = var.ingress_class_name
    rule {
      http {
        dynamic "path" {
          for_each = local.ingress_rules
          content {
            backend {
              service {
                name = path.value.service_name
                port {
                  number = path.value.service_port
                }
              }
            }
            path = path.value.service_path
          }
        }
      }
    }
    tls {
      secret_name = "tls-secret"
    }
  }
}
```